# Trouble adding trusted location in Word 2007

Tags: ms-word

I have a mapped network drive `\\10.0.0.99\Share --> Z:\`, the actual computer name of 10.0.0.99 is `ShareServer-PC`.
I try to add `Z:\` as trusted location in Word 2007, without success:

> the path you have entered cannot be used as a trusted location for security reasons. choose another location or a specific folder.

Nor does `\\10.0.0.99`

I can add `ShareServer-PC`, but yet, when I open word documents from `Z;\...`, it still showing up the `macros disabled...` warning.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was solved.
The mapping was `Z:\ <--> 10.0.0.99` and when changed to `Z:\ <--> ShareServer-PC` everything started to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add it by the locally mapped drive letter. But you should be able to add it using the UNC share name \my-server\myshare or even \myserver should work but that makes the entire server trusted.

Also don't forget to check the box "Allow Trusted Locations on my network (not recommended) otherwise you can't add any of those locations.

Comment: I know, and I did. But when I open a doc from `Z:\` it is marked as not trusted, even though Z <==> UNC

Comment: Do you have the box "Trust subfolders in this location" checked where you add the location?

Comment: Under "Trusted Documents" do you have "Allow documents on a network to be trusted"

Comment: mapping the drive to the unc instead of the ip address solved the issue. thanks for tyring to help, appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some context to this - I believe the reason **you can't add a network drive to Trusted Locations** is because end users can remap drives to anywhere they like, even `\\localhost\c$\users\user\downloads` for example.

I've even tried via GPO and the mapped drive shows in the list of Trusted Sites, but has no effect.

I don't know why IPs are not taking effect either, but **SMB paths seem the only way**.